# Calling additional scripts as jobs

Tags: powershell

I have a master script that is attempting to execute additional scripts against a list of servers it pulls from a table. I would like these additional scripts to be called asynchronously.

These additional scripts require a number of parameters that I cannot for the life of me get passed from the main script.

The child scripts all use the following parameters:

```
param(
[string]$sqlsrv=$null,
[string]$db=$null,
[string]$server=$null,
[string]$instance=$null
)
```

These values are generated by the master script. I can easily call anyone of the child scripts from the command line like so:

.\serverstatus.ps1 test test1 test2 test3
Where test,test1,test2,test3 are the parameter values.

The only way I am aware of to call these child scripts asynchronously is using Start-Job. I cannot get Start-Job to accept my parameters. This seems to get me close:

```
Start-Job serverstatus.ps1 $sqlsrv $db $server $instance
```

I get this error:

```
`Start-Job : Cannot bind parameter 'InitializationScript'.
Cannot convert the "TESTSERVER" value of type "System.String" to type System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
    At C:\SQLPS\ServerList.ps1:69 char:12
        + Start-Job <<<<  serverstatus.ps1 $sqlsrv $db $server $instance
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Job], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand`
```

I have tried many methods of passing these parameters based on information found online. I just can't seem to make any progress. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*

Ok using your example, I am attempting to do the same. here are my results. The output of Receive-Job is what is killing me. I can't seem to get anything meaningful from it.

**ProcessServers.ps1**

```
{Gathers a list of servers and instances}
Start-Job -FilePath .\serverstatus.ps1 -ArgumentList $sqlsrv,$destdb,$server,$instance
```

If I just write-output on the Start-Job line, all variables are properly populated as expected. Output looks like so:

```
Start-Job -FilePath .\GetServerDetails.ps1 -ArgumentList RADC00,ServerHistory,RADCHR01,RADCHR01
```

For testing purposes, I have modified GetServerDetails.ps1 to simply output the passed parameters. It looks as so:

**GetServerDetails.ps1**

```
param($sqlsrv,$db,$server,$instance)
"Parameters are: $sqlsrv, $destdb, $server, $instance"
```

So from the command line I run:

```
Start-Job -FilePath .\GetServerDetails.ps1 -ArgumentList RADC00,ServerHistory,RADCHR01,RADCHR01
```

Instead of output like you get, I get this:

```
PS C:\SQLPS> Start-Job -FilePath .\GetServerDetails.ps1 -ArgumentList RADC00,ServerHistory,RADCHR01,RADCHR01

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location             Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------             -------
37              Job37           Running    True            localhost            param($sqlsrv,$destdb,...

PS C:\SQLPS> Receive-Job -id 37
PS C:\SQLPS>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-ArgumentList` parameter on `Start-Job` to pass in your parameters.  The `ArgumentList` parameter should be the last parameter for that command e.g.:

```
PS> Get-Content script.ps1
param($p1, $p2, $p3)

"p1 is $p1, p2 is $p2, p3 is $p3"

PS> Start-Job -FilePath .\script.ps1 -ArgumentList 1,"2",(get-date)

Id    Name State      HasMoreData     Location  Command
--    ---- -----      -----------     --------  -------
1     Job1 Running    True            localhost param($p1, $p2, $p3)...


PS> Receive-Job -id 1
p1 is 1, p2 is 2, p3 is 03/11/2011 16:42:26
```

Comment: Updated answer to add an example of the usage of `-ArgumentList`.

Comment: I added additional information to the question. I am attempting to mimic your test but getting different results.

Comment: I just recreated your script and I have the same issue. I cannot remove it either. "Remove-Job : The command cannot remove the job with the 5 session identifier because the job is not finished. To remove
 the job, first stop the job, or use the Force parameter." It's as thought it is hung...

Comment: @Kenneth:  This is sort of a long-shot, but I had a problem running jobs on an XP system a while back.  When you start several jobs, you will notice the job number increases by 2 for each job.  That is because every job you start has a hidden child-job associated with it.  With the problem I observed, the child jobs (which you can get info on by explictly specifying the job name) were hanging in some sort of "Starting" state.  You might want to check for this.  Unfortunately, even though I have seen a solution for this problem, I don't remember what it is.  This may occur on non-XP systems.

Comment: @OldFart: This is exactly what is happening. I will have to go at this problem from a different angle I guess. Thank you.

Comment: I did a bit of research that suggested the SCOM management components were related to this problem. I removed the SCOM 2007 R2 components and this issue has disappeared.

Comment: Another way to work around the hanging job is to use a scriptblock call to Powershell.exe using the -file parameter instead of using the -FilePath parameter of Start-Job directly.

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param([string]$scriptPath, [string]$someParam) Powershell.exe -file "$scriptPath" $someParam} -ArgumentList $scriptPath, $someParam

The double-quotes are important if you have to pass additional parameters to the script itself (which I imagine you usually would). Also note the commas in the Start-Job call (but not in the call to Powershell within the script block.)